# Pie 3d and Pie charts in Excel using Openxml C#

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, openxml, pie-chart

I am trying to create a Pie Chart and a Pie 3d chart in Excel using Open XML SDK 2.0 in C#.NetCore 2.0 platform .I searched for an example on google but found nothing, Not even a small example. All they say is to use Open XML SDK productivity tool. to see the code. but I don't understand it because it generates too much code to understand the concept. If anyone has a simple example then please share your Knowledge. It will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Please go to the below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162594/create-pie-chart-on-excel-using-openxml/62860382#62860382