# How to create Pivot table using OpenXML SDK along with chart with filters

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

We are working on a migration project where Excel (.xlsx) files were generated using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Currently in the migrated application we are using **Open XML SDK** to generate Excel files using C#. Excel files have Pivot Tables, Bar Charts and Pie Charts. We were able to create some simple Bar Chart and Pie chart using the available documentation.

But we are looking for some help in achieving below functionalities:
• Creating/Updating a Pivot table based on pivot filters (combination of columns present in the pivot data source)
• Creating/Updating Bar Chart based on pivot filters or chart filters.
• Creating/Updating Pie Chart based on pivot filters or chart filters.
• Adding labels in the Bar Chart • Adding labels in the Pie Chart

Attached below few screenshots to illustrate the expected pivot table & chart behavior, which needs to create using Open XML SDK in C#:

Some ref. we found over internet like: [Create Pie Chart on Excel using OpenXml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162594/create-pie-chart-on-excel-using-openxml)

But solution which is provided in the ref link is based on the direct data to create Pie chart, and in our project specific, first we need to create pivot table from the database record and then with the created pivot table data, further I need to create pie chart and bar chart, and this way we are looking for some help or any sample code reference to achieve below functionalities (screen shots already attached for the ref):

• Creating/Updating a Pivot table based on pivot filters (combination of columns present in the pivot data source)
• Creating/Updating Bar Chart based on pivot filters or chart filters.
• Creating/Updating Pie Chart based on pivot filters or chart filters.
• Adding labels in the Bar Chart • Adding labels in the Pie Chart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdxDF.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn5jV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool, it is primitive but it works. Kind of reverse engineering process.

Create the Excel with the expected format and data.
Open it in the tool, click "Reflect Code", it will generate a .cs class that can generate the excel.

for how to install please read here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/466445/where-can-i-download-open-xml-sdk-2-5-productivity

I put the snippets here, the source is too long I moved to https://github.com/Otaku-Projects/ReportEngine/wiki/Open-XML-SDK-Quick-Guide

**For the code with filter**

```
// Generates content of pivotTablePart1.
        private void GeneratePivotTablePart1Content(PivotTablePart pivotTablePart1)
...
            Location location1 = new Location(){ Reference = "A5:B9", FirstHeaderRow = (UInt32Value)1U, FirstDataRow = (UInt32Value)1U, FirstDataColumn = (UInt32Value)1U, RowPageCount = (UInt32Value)1U, ColumnsPerPage = (UInt32Value)1U };
...

            PivotField pivotField10 = new PivotField(){ Axis = PivotTableAxisValues.AxisPage, ShowAll = false };
...            
            PageFields pageFields1 = new PageFields(){ Count = (UInt32Value)1U };
            PageField pageField1 = new PageField(){ Field = 9, Hierarchy = -1 };
            pageFields1.Append(pageField1);
...
            pivotTableDefinition1.Append(pageFields1);
```

**For the code without filter**

```
// Generates content of pivotTablePart1.
        private void GeneratePivotTablePart1Content(PivotTablePart pivotTablePart1)
...
            Location location1 = new Location(){ Reference = "A5:B9", FirstHeaderRow = (UInt32Value)1U, FirstDataRow = (UInt32Value)1U, FirstDataColumn = (UInt32Value)1U };
...
            PivotField pivotField10 = new PivotField(){ ShowAll = false };
...
// removed PageFields pageFields1
...
// removed pivotTableDefinition1.Append(pageFields1);
```

I put Pivot on "sheet2", for the field = 9, it refers to the column J (Zero-based index) at "sheet1" it was defined under GeneratePivotTableCacheDefinitionPart1Content()

`WorksheetSource worksheetSource1 = new WorksheetSource(){ Reference = "A1:K7", Sheet = "Sheet1" };`